# Node EXEC ignoring parameters

Tags: node.js, cordova, child-process

Running the following command `cordova build android --release -- -- --packageType=bundle` it works fine on the cmd but when running it with node using the exec function it ignores the parameters? Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('cordova build android --release -- -- --packageType=bundle', async function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if(error){
                return log(error.message)
            }

            callBack && callBack(stdout);
            return resolve();
        })
```

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem with a command like `cordova run browser -- --port=8005`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding too many `--`
It's

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=bundle
```